# count amount of 'where not exist any' in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset with Membership information. An organisation can have a membership to different categories of memberships. One of these categories is a 'deelmarkt'. I now want to see the amount of organisations that do not have a membership with type 'deelmarkt'.

I tried:
_AantalLidmaatschappenNietDeelmarkt =
CALCULATE(COUNT(DIM_ORGANISATIE[Id]), FILTER(FCT_LIDMAATSCHAPPEN, FCT_LIDMAATSCHAPPEN[Categorie] <> "Deelmarkten"))

But this won't work as it will count the organisation where the category is not Deelmarkten. But I want to count the memberships 'where not exists any' in the category deelmarkten.

How do I write this in DAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Organizations w/o Deelmarkt = 
COUNTROWS ( 
    FILTER ( 
        DIM_ORGANISATIE , 
        CALCULATE ( 
            COUNTROWS ( FCT_LIDMAATSCHAPPEN ) ,
            FCT_LIDMAATSCHAPPEN[Categorie] = "Deelmarkten"
        ) = BLANK ()
    )
)
```